# Problem of JsonSerializer.Serialize with different language character

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my code:

```
public class TestModel{
  public string AAA{get;set;}
  public string BBB{get;set;}
}
        [Route("Test")]
        public async Task<string> Test()
        {           
            TestModel _TestModel=new TestModel(){AAA="123",BBB="привет123"};
            string JSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_TestModel, typeof(TestModel));            
            return JSON;
        }
```

When I ran the `program`, the `JSON` convert successfully.

However, the character which is not English or number can not convert correctly but only displays some strange string such as **`"\u65B0"`**.

I think maybe it is the problem of encoding. However, it seems I can't set the encoding in the `JsonSerializer.Serialize`.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407611/6299857

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Thanks for helping me and I wonder if there is a way for the origin JsonSerializer of Microsoft? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by modify the `JsonSerializer.Serialize` like this:

```
string JSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_TestModel, typeof(TestModel), new JsonSerializerOptions() { Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Create(System.Text.Unicode.UnicodeRanges.All) });
```